# How to get non matched columns by comparing two datatables

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Hi all I am having two data tables as follows

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("ColumnId");
dt1.Columns.Add("Column2");
dt1.Columns.Add("Column3");
dt1.Columns.Add("Column4");

dt1.Rows.Add("1, "TestData", "TestData1", "TestData2");

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("ColumnId");
dt2.Columns.Add("Column2");
dt2.Columns.Add("Column3");
dt2.Columns.Add("Column4");

dt2.Rows.Add("1, "TestData1", "TestData1", "TestData2");
```

I know how to get the non matched row by writing linq query as follows

```
var differences = dt1.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable(),DataRowComparer.Default);
var v = differences.Any() ? differences.CopyToDataTable() : new DataTable();
```

But this is giving me entire row but what I need is only the non-matched columns with ColumnId like

```
ColumnnId    Column2
   1         TestData1
```

One more point is my data can be changed in any of the columns, in that case I need to list out all the columns else the non matched columns. Also my column names can vary so I need the code in a dynamic way such that it should match with any column names specified

Comment: You need a left out join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.  A regular join won't give you the 2nd item that didn't equal.  Sometimes all you have to do is reverse the two tables by joining the 2nd with 1st.

Comment: If you've got the rows already based on the fact they are different, you're halfway there.   That means that the resulting datatable you have there (v)   already only contains rows that had differences.   If you do a Foreach on that table's Rows collection, using a unique identifier for the row, you can find its match and then roll through the columns with another loop.

Comment: Can you please show an example of your wanted output for the cases where: There are multiples not matched rows (and/or) There are multiples not matched columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Like user1895086 said, if ColumnId is common between the tables, ie you choose which rows to compare in each table by the ID, then all you have to do is do a double for loop to find the rest of the information.  I can provide psuedo-code below.  At the end, differenceByField will contain a mapping of the column ID the list of column names that were different.

for example:

```
        Dictionary differencesByField = new Dictionary();

        for each row in differences.Rows
        {
            var columnId = ColumnId of row

            DataRow otherRow = get the row in dt2 with same columnId

            differencesByField[columnId] = new List<string>();

            for each column in differences.Columns
            {
                string val = get value of column from row
                string otherVal = get value of column from otherRow

                if (val != otherVal)
                {
                    differencesByField[columnId].Add(col.ColumnName);
                }
            }
        }
```